# Firebase hosting rewrite rules based on language of browser

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have a Firebase hosted website that contains an `index_fr.html` and `index_nl.html`.
How can I create a rewrite rules that uses the user agent language to serve the correct `index_nl` or `index_fr` page (without using Firebase functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update August 12th, 2020:** Firebase Hosting now supports [i18n internationalization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites).

---

<strike>Firebase Hosting rewrites are based on the requested path only. There is not support for such conditional rewrites in the Firebase Hosting configuration.</strike>

You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

Comment: Hi @Frank, we seam to run into each other frequently when I am asking questions about Firebase. Thank you very much for all your prompt replies. Maybe we can meetup once in one of the Firebase Summit events :-) anyway, change request filed!