# Firebase hosting redirect to the subdirectory of preferred language found in browser config

Tags: angular, firebase, internationalization, firebase-hosting

I deployed an Angular `i18n` app, hence I have two builds - one for german speaking users and one for english speaking users/the rest of the world.

To deploy I've already adjusted `firebase.json` to redirect to `/de` subdirectory on start. Is there a way to redirect to the subdirectory of the preferred language defined in the browser configuration (or en if your preferred language is not found)?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/tudor",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source" : "/",
        "destination" : "/de",
        "type" : 301
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/en/**",
        "destination": "/en/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/de/**",
        "destination": "/de/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Apache equivalent:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.myapp.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory "/var/www">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^../index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (..) $1/index.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /es/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^es [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is not possible with Firebase Hosting at the moment. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251596/firebase-hosting-rewrite-rules-based-on-language-of-browser

Comment: Firebase Hosting now supports i18n internationalization. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383442/5861618) for more details