# Implementing localized 404 page with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, localization, firebase-hosting

Say my web app has two locales: English(`myapp.com/en/`) and French(`myapp.com/fr/`). I want to localize my 404 pages, so that request to `myapp.com/en/non-existent` or `myapp.com/non-existent` would return an English version of the 404 page and request to `myapp.comm/fr/non-existent` would return a French one.

However, it seems like Firebase Hosting does not provide such functionality by default, as it only allows a single 404 page([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#404))

So, is there a way of implementing a localized 404 page with Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of August 12th 2020, Firebase Hosting now includes support for [i18n internalization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites).

Here's how to use it:

1. Create a new directory to host these localized files (e.g `localized`) under your `public` directory.
2. Update your `firebase.json` file to include a reference to this new directory:

```
// firebase.json

"hosting": {

  "public": "public",

  "ignore": [
     // ...
  ],

  "i18n": {
    "root": "/localized"  // directory that contains your "i18n content"
  }

  // ...
}
```

3. Under the `localized` directory, create a new directory named `fr`, and that's where you can add your french `404.html` file.
4. Run `firebase deploy` to deploy your site and now your french users should be redirected to the correct page :)

See the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites#country-and-language-codes) for more information on country and language codes.

Answer (score 5):

#### This answer is outdated. Firebase now supports this functionality by default. See [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383442/11105280).

---

One way of achieving this functionality is by using [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

```
{
  ...
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/fr/**",
        "destination": "/fr/404.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/en/404.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This will serve the `/fr/404.html/` page for unmatched requests inside `/fr/` directory and `/en/404.html` for any other unmatched request.

The downside of this approach is that the returned status code is 200 instead of 404.

---

A better solution is to rewrite unmatched requests [to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function)  that return the needed 404 page and the 404 status code. Note, that the 404 pages have to be located in `functions/lib` directory, not `public`.

Also, with the use of proper `Cache-Control` header, you can allow the Firebase Hosting to cache the output of the Functions so that they don't have to run every time a 404 page is requested.

Firebase config:

```
{
  ...
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/fr/**",
        "function": "pageNotFoundFr"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "pageNotFound"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The functions:

```js
exports.pageNotFound = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000")
    res.status(404).sendFile("en/404.html", {root: __dirname})
})

exports.pageNotFoundFr = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000")
    res.status(404).sendFile("fr/404.html", {root: __dirname})
})
```

But this approach duplicates the code and can be messy in case you have more languages.

---

It would be better to extract the request handler into a function:

```js
exports.pageNotFound = functions.https.onRequest(notFoundHanler("en"))
exports.pageNotFoundFr = functions.https.onRequest(notFoundHanler("fr"))

function notFoundHandler(lang) {
    return function (req, res) {
        res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000")
        res.status(404).sendFile(`${lang}/404.html`, {root: __dirname})
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** I filed a feature request for multiple 404 pages to Firebase and they replied that it will be taken into consideration.

Comment: You can use `type: 404` for the return http response code :)

Comment: @frunkad Seems like `type` field is only available for [redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects), not rewrites